# Can I store data, like an API key while the browser is active?

Tags: api, google-chrome-extension, storage

I'm currently working on a chrome extension which retrieves an API key. I have everything sort of working, the only problem I'm facing, is the storage of said API key.
I'm looking for a way to store the key for the time that the user has his/her browser active. I have it currently on local storage.

```
   //save the apikey in HTML5 localstorage
   localStorage.setItem('apikey', data.api_key);
```

Comment: And your problem is? It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: "I'm looking for a way to store the key for the time that the user has his/her browser active." How can I store the API key so that it's reusable as long as the browser is open? Not the tab, but the browser.

Comment: So, your code is in a content script? Then it's a problem indeed, because `localStorage` is per domain.

Comment: Cookies are too low security for the key, and session storage gets cleared after the tab closes, but local storage keeps it too long..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome hasn't a reliable close event to let you clean the localStorage apikey key when the user close the browser.

You can save your key in a local variable in the background page.  This page will be active until the browser shutdowns.